# Login Symfony 4.2 Method checkCredentials return false

Tags: php, authentication, symfony4

When I try to log into the system I get information that I enter incorrect data. The method returns false with the message:

> Authentication failed because
>   App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator::checkCredentials() did not return
>   true.

Logging I do based on the symfony documentation
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup

[image]

Entity User

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * The unique auto incremented primary key.
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * The internal primary identity key.
     *
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     */
    private $uid;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     *
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     checkMX = true
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password bcrypt
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 50)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *      groups = {"Registration", "ChangeDetails"}
     * )
     *
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min=3,
     *      max=50,
     *      groups = {"Registration", "ChangeDetails"}
     * )
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 50)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *      groups = {"Registration", "ChangeDetails"}
     * )
     *
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min=3,
     *      max=50,
     *      groups = {"Registration", "ChangeDetails"}
     * )
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length = 10000,)
     *
     *
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      max=10000,
     *      groups = {"Registration", "ChangeDetails"}
     * )
     *
     * @var string A detailed description of the user available to the application administrator
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="account_locked", type="boolean")
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $accountLocked = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="register_date", type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $createDate;

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUid(): int
    {
        return $this->uid;
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->registerDate = new \DateTime();
        $this->uid = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    }

    /**
     * Get name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname.
     *
     * @param string $surname
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSurname(string $surname): User
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSurname(): string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set accountLocked.
     *
     * @param bool $accountLocked
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAccountLocked(bool $accountLocked): User
    {
        $this->accountNonLocked = $accountLocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get accountLocked.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getAccountLocked(): bool
    {
        return $this->accountNonLocked;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
        ]);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName(string $name): User
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

SecurityConroller

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/login", name="login")
         */
        public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
        {
            $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
            $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

            return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error' => $error,
                ]);
        }
    }
```

Security/Loginformauthenticator

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $router;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, RouterInterface $router, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $param = $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
        return $param;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('panel_dashboard'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('login');
    }
}
```

security.uaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt


    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    access_control:
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/panel, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Form login

```
   <form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform">
        {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}
        <h3 class="text-center m-b-20">{% trans %}Sign In{% endtrans %}</h3>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans %}Username{% endtrans %}" required> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input  name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{% trans %}Password{% endtrans %}" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">    
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input name="_remember_me" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">{% trans %}Remember me{% endtrans %}</label>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="ml-auto">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="to-recover" class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-lock m-r-5"></i>{% trans %} Forgot pwd{% endtrans %}?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 p-b-20">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info btn-rounded" type="submit">{% trans %}Log In{% endtrans %}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

UserFixtures

```
class UserFixtures extends Fixture
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $passwordEncoder;

    /**
     * UserFixtures constructor.
     *
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     */
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $usersList = [
            [
                'name' => 'Tomasz',
                'surname' => 'Kowalik',
                'description' => 'Vestibulum non ipsum. Curabitur egestas. Integer hendrerit purus consectetuer adipiscing elit. In sodales in, elementum vel, velit. Suspendisse fermen',
                'email' => 'tomek@test.pl',
                'password' => 'password',
                'role' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                'points' => '0',
            ],

        ];

        foreach ($usersList as $userDetails) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->setName($userDetails['name'])
                    ->setSurname($userDetails['surname'])
                    ->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $userDetails['surname']))
                    ->setDescription($userDetails['description'])
                    ->setEmail($userDetails['email'])
                    ->setPoints($userDetails['points'])
                    ->setRoles([$userDetails['role']])
                    ->setCreateDate(new \DateTime());

            $this->addReference('user-'.$userDetails['surname'], $user);

            $manager->persist($user);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the hash saved in the database manually and after encoding the password, the password did not give a hash from the database. The reason is the error:

```
setPassword ($ this-> passwordEncoder-> encodePassword ($ user, $ userDetails ['surname'])) // surname -> password
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Switching from old to new encoding method the length of my password was too long to fit in the db, as such the hashed password was truncated.